# Create list from multiple lists with a property is equal

Tags: list, flutter, dart

My row lists:

```
List rowlist = [Student(name: 'John',age: 12),
             Student(name: 'Kity',age: 13),
             Student(name: 'Micle',age: 14),
             Student(name: 'Jack',age: 12),
             Student(name: 'Cha',age: 13),
             Student(name: 'Duc',age: 13),
             Student(name: 'Ran',age: 12)]
```

Expected result:

```
List result = [
               [
                Student(name: 'John',age: 12),
                Student(name: 'Jack',age: 12),
                Student(name: 'Ran',age: 12),
               ],
               [
                Student(name: 'Kity',age: 13),
                Student(name: 'Cha',age: 13),
                Student(name: 'Duc',age: 13),
               ],
               [
                Student(name: 'Micle',age: 14),
               ]
             ]
```

I need to create a new list of list wherein each list is added by `Student` with `age` field is equal. What is the best way for the result?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [collection package](https://pub.dev/packages/collection). You can use the `groupListsBy` method to group all of the students by age.

```dart
Map<int, List<Student>> result = rowlist.groupListsBy((student) => student.age);
```

The above however, returns the data as a `Map<int, List<Student>`. You can convert this to a `List<List<Student>>` by calling `.values.toList()`.

```dart
List<List<Student>> result = rowlist.groupListsBy((student) => student.age).values.toList();
```

Complete example:

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main() {
  List<Student> rowlist = [
    Student(name: 'John', age: 12),
    Student(name: 'Kity', age: 13),
    Student(name: 'Micle', age: 14),
    Student(name: 'Jack', age: 12),
    Student(name: 'Cha', age: 13),
    Student(name: 'Duc', age: 13),
    Student(name: 'Ran', age: 12),
  ];

  List<List<Student>> result =
      rowlist.groupListsBy((student) => student.age).values.toList();

  print(result);
}

class Student {
  final String name;
  final int age;
  const Student({required this.name, required this.age});
  @override
  String toString() => 'Student(name: $name, age: $age)';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without any package also.

```
List rowlist = [
  Student(name: 'John', age: 12),
  Student(name: 'Kity', age: 13),
  Student(name: 'Micle', age: 14),
  Student(name: 'Jack', age: 12),
  Student(name: 'Cha', age: 13),
  Student(name: 'Duc', age: 13),
  Student(name: 'Ran', age: 12)
];

void main() {
  Map<int, List<Student>> groupMap = {};

  for (final s in rowlist) {
    if (groupMap.containsKey(s.age)) {
      groupMap[s.age]!.add(s);
    } else {
      groupMap[s.age] = [s];
    }
  }

  final result = groupMap.entries.map((e) => e.value).toList();
  
  print(result);
}

class Student {
  Student({required this.name, required this.age});
  final String name;
  final int age;

  @override
  String toString() => '$name - $age';
}
```